# Getting % like values when creating cookie with object value in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to add object value in res.cookie and send to browser, cookies are setting perfectly but value is showing with some encoded strings like `j%3A%7B%2` instead of a stringify object.

tried with JSON.stringify(obj) as Well.

**without stringify**
[image]
[image]

**with stringify**
[image]
[image]

Any idea what I'm missing here? I'm expecting a stringify value in cookie

packages:
"express": "4.17.1",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",

Comment: The json string gets url encoded. To avoid this, you can encode it as base64 and save the base64 string as cookie. On the client you can decode the base64 string to get your json string and decode it back to a plain js object

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking at is the url-encoded version of the stringified JSON. To make sure that the string is url-safe some characters have been escaped and that's why you see the percentage signs. You can decode the value using the [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) method that's built into most browsers.